# XML Schema duplicate element values

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

Let's say i have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tree xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Leaf>
        <Address>0.0.1.0</Address>
      </Leaf>
      <Leaf>
        <Address>0.0.1.1</Address>
      </Leaf>
      <Leaf>
        <Address>0.0.1.2</Address>
      </Leaf>
</Tree>
```

how do i ensure there are no two leafs with identical addresses using an xsd file? Ive tried using the  tag with no luck. This is how my xsd file currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
<xs:element name="Tree">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Leaf">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Address"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:unique name="address-name-is-unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="Leaf"/>
      <xs:field xpath="Address"/>

    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Im trying to make it so if there happens to be a situation where something like this happens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tree xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Leaf>
    <Address>0.0.1.0</Address>
  </Leaf>
  <Leaf>
    <Address>0.0.1.1</Address>
  </Leaf>
  <Leaf>
    <Address>0.0.1.1</Address>
  </Leaf>
</Tree>
```

it will pull out an error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you've overlooked that Leaf and Address are in a namespace, so in the XPath expressions the names need to be qualified with a prefix bound to that namespace.

Comment: Add a namespace prefix to the element names in the path expression, and add a namespace declaration that binds that prefix to the right namespace.